# AWS KMS How to use Decrypt function Java

Tags: java, encryption, amazon-web-services, key-management

My question might sound too obvious but I am new to Amazon KMS. 
After reading a lot of docs on AWS I understood that if I am using CMK directly for encryption and decryption I can directly do it by creating encrypt and decrypt request.
But what I am not clear is when I generate a data key and debug using that,the documentation says I need to pass encrypted data key to decrypt API and I will get plain text key which I can use to debug text on my "OWN".
I don't understand this part. Can anyone please explain this and give a small example on decryption using data keys.
Thanks in advance

My Sample code:

```
public String decrypt(String encryptedTextString) {
    ByteBuffer encryptedText = ByteBuffer.wrap(Base64.getDecoder().decode(encryptedTextString));
    DecryptRequest req=new DecryptRequest().withCiphertextBlob(encryptedText);
    ByteBuffer plainText = client.decrypt(req).getPlaintext();
    return new String(plainText.array());
}

public String encrypt(String plainTextString) {
    ByteBuffer plainText = ByteBuffer.wrap(Base64.getDecoder().decode(plainTextString));
    EncryptRequest req = new EncryptRequest().withKeyId(new String(plainTextKey.array()))
            .withPlaintext(plainText);
    ByteBuffer encryptedText =client.encrypt(req).getCiphertextBlob();
    return new String(encryptedText.array());
}

AWSKMSCryprography() {
    this.setCredential(new ClearCredential());
    this.genrateKey();
}

private void genrateKey() {
    GenerateDataKeyRequest request = new GenerateDataKeyRequest();
    request.setKeyId(keyID);
    request.setKeySpec("AES_128");
    GenerateDataKeyResult dataKeyResult = client.generateDataKey(request);
    plainTextKey = dataKeyResult.getPlaintext();
    encryptedKey = dataKeyResult.getCiphertextBlob();

}
```

Comment: I think they just mean that you can encrypt/decrypt with a key that you generated yourself for testing purposes.

Comment: @MaartenBodewes Thanks,So does it mean that the above code snippet is enough for doing encryption and decryption,because right now I dont want the overhead of storing encrypted key alongwith encrypted text???

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm new to using KMS as well but the tutorial documentation on using encrypt and decrypt is misleading with using the encrypt and decrypt methods. The API documentation for both [AWSKMSClient.generateDataKey](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaSDK/latest/javadoc/com/amazonaws/services/kms/AWSKMSClient.html#generateDataKey(com.amazonaws.services.kms.model.GenerateDataKeyRequest)) and [AWSKKMSClient.encrypt](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaSDK/latest/javadoc/com/amazonaws/services/kms/AWSKMSClient.html#encrypt(com.amazonaws.services.kms.model.EncryptRequest)) point out that `encrypt()` is for specific use cases and a different pattern should be use for using the local key.

A more useful example of KMS can be found in the [dynamodb encryption library](https://github.com/awslabs/aws-dynamodb-encryption-java/blob/master/src/main/java/com/amazonaws/services/dynamodbv2/datamodeling/encryption/providers/DirectKmsMaterialProvider.java). Also see http://netnix.org/2015/04/19/aes-encryption-with-hmac-integrity-in-java/ for an overview of basic encryption in general.